# IIS Web Site "Page Can Not Be Displayed" After Server Was Upgraded From Windows 2008 to Windows 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, internet-explorer, iis, wireshark

The web site is an Asp.NET MVC one with Bootstrap and Jquery.  It works fine under Windows 2008.  However when the server was upgraded to 2012.  We received "Page can not be displayed" error.

The IE 11 browser is managed by client and we have not way to change the settings to debug.  The only error message we can see is "aborted" in IE.

In server side, we have Wireshark to capture some info as below -
[image] 
What are the possible issues and solutions?

Comment: flash, ah ah, saviour of the internet! are you using third party 'video' content manages like adobeflash.js? flowplayer.js or analytics.js(a goole api) . see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/02/28/activex-filtering-for-consumers/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/05/02/activex-filtering-for-developers/ To detect if a web site is using Flash or outdated flash feature testing using ActiveXObject go Tools>Manage Addons>Currently loaded addons.... flash appears in the listing if the site is trying to use flash or look in the Tasks Managers process list.

Comment: also use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE security zone a site is mapped to..... Intranet sites by default only run 32bit versions of ActiveX, Internet (public access) sites, by default only run 64bit versions on (64bit cpu's).... clients should be updated with updates from November of last year which included Critical Security Updates for Flash and blocking of out of date ActiveX controls (eg. Macomedia flash, not Adobe Flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from router's wrong settings.  Somehow the router lost the original requester.